# SQL - Join Two Tables About The Same Entities

Tags: sql

I have created two tables, each table contains some entries that are about the same entity. How can I write a query to join the entries and create a unified entry in another table?

sorry for the confusion guys. I should provide a simple example.

My two tables look similar to the below,

Table 1: `Name, ID, email, city, state, phone`
Table 2: `LastName, FirstName, email, gender, ID`

Comment: what do you mean by 'about the same entity'?

Comment: maybe you could share structure, code, anything would be good and sure will help with providing answers

Comment: Hi Orbit, sorry for the confusion. I should provide a simple example. 

Table 1(Name, ID, email, city, state, phone)
Table 2(LastName, FirstName, email, gender, ID)

Comment: Also please state the RDBMS and Version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that ID is the primary key that links the two tables. This query takes selected columns from each table and inserts them into table @U3.

```
declare @U3 Table(ID int, FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50),  
                  city varchar(50), [state] varchar(50), phone varchar(50),
                  email varchar(50), gender varchar(50))

insert @U3
  select u1.ID, u2.FirstName, u2.LastName, u1.email,
         u1.city, u1.state,u1.phone, u2.gender
  from Table1 u1 
    join Table2 u2 on u2.ID=u1.ID

select * from @U3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO
    c (machine, address)
(   SELECT
           a.machine, a.address
    FROM
           a
    UNION
    SELECT
           b.machine, b.address
    FROM
           b
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (SELECT T1.Name,T1.email,T1.city,T1.state,T1.phone,
T2.Lastname,T2.Firstname,T2.gender FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID)
```

Table C should contain all fields in the result set of the join of Tables 1 and 2. except for the duplicate ID/email

Edited to show all fields